# Varnish: Save objects from being evicted from the cache

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-4

Is it possible to mark objects in the varnish cache in a way that they will not get evicted from the cache if the cache is full?
Some of the requests on our server take a very long time to render, and result in a small xml response. This resource isn't called that often and we want to make sure that it stays in the cache.
When the space is running out in the cache varnish starts removing objects that are old and not called often. We would like to assign a priority to the cached objects and influence the algorithm that removes objects from the cache.
Is that possible? And if yes, how?